# Azure VM cpu core unused calculation and cost saving

Tags: azure

I am trying to query our Azure VMs to get total CPU cores and used CPU cores so to find available CPU core. This way to find which VMs are not being used and take further actions to save cost.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure VM cpu core unused calculation and cost saving

You can check the details of unused `CPU` cores for `Azure VMs` and calculate the total, used, and available CPU cores for each `VM` using `PowerShell`.

**Powershell**

```
    $rgname = "MANAGEMENT_MIGRATION-RESOURCES"
    $startTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)  # Adjust the time window as needed
    $endTime = Get-Date
    
    # Get all VMs in the resource group
    $vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname
    
    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
        $vmName = $vm.Name
        $vmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
    
        # Retrieve CPU metrics
        $cpuMetrics = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $vm.Id -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -Aggregation Average
    
        $totalCores = Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMName $vmName | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $vmSize } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfCores
        $usedCores = [Math]::Min($totalCores, ($totalCores * ($cpuMetrics.Data.Average | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 100))
        $availableCores = $totalCores - $usedCores
    
        Write-Host "VM Name: $vmName"
        Write-Host "VM Size: $vmSize"
        Write-Host "Total CPU Cores: $totalCores"
        Write-Host "Used CPU Cores: $usedCores"
        Write-Host "Available CPU Cores: $availableCores"
        Write-Host "--------------------------"
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference : [Get-AzVMSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmsize?view=azps-10.2.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.1.0) &  [Get-AzMetric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-10.2.0)

Comment: Thank you Venkat , i will try this and let you know. Can you give some ideas around saving costs in VM optimizations .

Comment: Hi @swadesh, is the above solution working for you?

Comment: Thanks Venkat , its working , Can you please let me know if we want to represent this on a dashboard for VMs which have unused cores how can we go around this process